# Numpy Matplotlib array of complex numbers to plot 3d graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, complex-numbers

I am trying to plot `y=x^2+1` in python using `matplotlib` and `numpy` in 3D with `Re(x)`, `Im(x)` and `Re(f(x))` on the 3 axes. However, I'm getting an error and I don't know how to continue further.
Error:
`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (400,) and requested shape (20,)`

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

def f(x):
        return abs(x)**2

a = np.arange(-10,10,1)
b = np.arange(-10,10,1)
carray = np.zeros(1, dtype=complex)

for i in range(-10,10,1):
        for j in range(-10,10,1):
                cnumb = complex(i, j)
                carray = np.append(carray,cnumb)
#c = a + 1j*b
carray = np.delete(carray,0,0)
print(carray)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.plot(a,b,abs(carray))
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: a, b and carray need to have the same lenght. They are the x, y, z coordinates of points on the 3D plot. That is, the "first" point is plotted at coordinates a[0], b[0], carray[0].

Answer (score 1):

You have three issues:

- The way you create `carray` misses up with the expected shape
- Using `ax.plot` demands that all `a`, `b` and `carray` to have the same size as shown in this [example](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/lines3d_demo.py).
- You didn't use `f` function besides that its definition isn't what you want.

So, the following code fixes all these issues:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')


def f(x):
    return x**2 + 1   #<-- fixed


a = np.arange(-10,10,1)
b = np.arange(-10,10,1)
carray = np.zeros((len(a), len(b)), dtype=complex)  #<-- changed the declartion

for i in range(-10,10,1):
    for j in range(-10,10,1):
        carray[i, j] = complex(i, j)   #<-- to maintain the expected shape

carray = f(carray)  #<-- use f()

ax.contour3D(a, b, carray)     #<-- use contour3D instead of plot
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Which produces this graph:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code and it threw the following error. `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (400,) and requested shape (20,)`
So something is wrong with the dimension sizes that's why it can't plot it.
Your `a` and `b` array have the length of 20 while `carray` has 400. (because of the double for).